# Constants in Android SDK

Tags: android-layout

When using setVisibility(int) the int can be VISIBLE, INVISIBLE and GONE
These, when I look them up, have (obviously) set int values.
However, I cannot just put in (say) "GONE" because it is not recognised.
How can I import the definitions, or do i have to define them in my own code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put `import static android.view.View.GONE` beneath your imports and you can use the `GONE` constant directly without needing any additional qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

`android.view.View.GONE` they are constants defined in View

Comment: Thanks. So, do I use "android.view.View.GONE", or set my own int equal to that, import "android.view.View.*" or use it some other way?

Comment: just import and use it directly. That value is not guaranteed to be unchanged across different android versions.

Comment: I use it as "android.view.View.GONE".

Comment: Importing "android.view.View.*" and then using "GONE" does not work for some reason

Comment: importing doesn't work. You can only import `android.view.View` and then use View.GONE, since it is not a class, but a constant only.